# Regex to create a group from an entire line, or just up to a given token

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, end-of-line

I'm using a JavaScript Regex Engine.

The regex `^(.*?)\s*(?=[*\[]).*` will capture a group containing all the characters up to a `[` or `*` character. It works well with these lines, matching the entire line and capturing the first section:

```
This should be captured up to here[ but no further]
This should be captured up to this asterisk* but not after it*
```

However, I would like to also capture an entire line if it contains neither of these characters:

```
This entire line should be captured.
```

This regex `^(.*?)\s*(?=[*\[]).*|^(.*)$` will *match* the entire line, but it will not *capture* anything in group `\1`.

Is it possible to modify the lookahead so that it will also find `no more characters`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an end of the line anchor inside the positive lookahead assertion.

```
^(.*?)\s*(?=[*\[]|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rM8tU3/4)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(.*?)\s*(?=[*\[]|[^*\[]$)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jV9hE3/1)